# Have a permission problems running yo @superset-ui/superset

Tags: node.js, npm, apache-superset

following this page to customize Apache Superset: https://preset.io/blog/2020-07-02-hello-world/

I have the following when running: yo @superset-ui/superset

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/write-file-atomic/index.js:236
    throw err
    ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/root/.config/insight-nodejs/insight-yo.json.1971212867'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:498:3)
    at Function.writeFileSync [as sync] (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/write-file-atomic/index.js:212:13)
    at Conf.set store [as store] (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/conf/index.js:142:19)
    at Conf.set (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/conf/index.js:64:14)
    at Insight.set optOut [as optOut] (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/lib/index.js:56:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js:209:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14) {
  errno: -13,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'EACCES',
  path: '/root/.config/insight-nodejs/insight-yo.json.1971212867'
}
```

I tried to: sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm

All of the above folders and also
chmod ugo+rwx /root/.config all of them too...

Although root user should have access all of the folders by default as I understand. Nothing helps...

What could I do else?

Comment: Also somehow: insight-yo.json, become: insight-yo.json.1971212867

Comment: I use root since it's virtual maching. So exactly the reason, because I didn't want to have permission troubles...

Comment: Only one time the machine told me that using root may mess up permissions. But I don't do anything difficult on the machine, so I just ignored the warning. And the since root have access to all folders by default, how it could be messed up...

Comment: I will try to uninstall node and install nvm.

Comment: node --version v14.17.0, but pip uninstall node gives WARNING: Skipping node as it is not installed.

Comment: because installed globally?

Comment: trying to: npm ls -gp --depth=0 and awk -F/ '/node_modules/ && !/\/npm$/ {print $NF}' the machine hangs :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

under current user to whichever plugin-chart you created, give full permission:
sudo chmod 777 -R /path/to/the/plugin/folder